# nghttp2 w/Buildroot on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, curl, https, buildroot

I'm fairly new to buildroot and I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the "nghttp2" package added to my system so that I can utilize it in conjunction with curl on my embedded system.

I'm not too adept at adding custom packages so any help with the best way of going about this would be great.

NOTE: I've looked at the buildroot manual but it isn't too in-depth about how to go about the specifics, which is why I'm asking for more verbose details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just today, a patch was submitted on the Buildroot mailing list to add a package for nghttp2. It hasn't been merged yet due to minor details, but overall it works fine: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/945578/

Comment: Thank you for the information. Please excuse my ignorance but how would I go about adding this?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you for the information!